# Web Application Deployed on JBoss + Linux giving Jackson jar conflicts

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

Following Exception is being thrown while accessing the spring controllers on above configuration :-

```
ERROR apiCategory - In error jsp with Exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonMessageConverter' defined in ServletContext resource 

[/WEB-INF/SMServlet-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class 

[org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
```

Comment: Looks like your are missing jackson-mapper-*.jar in your environment.

Comment: Did you put your spring libs into a module or are you shipping them with the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am shipping them with war and after searching a lot i have found out a solution for this problem. I solved this issue by going through this link :- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/150042. There is a small change in jboss-classloading.xml which is as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading   xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" 
            **domain="warname/contextname"**
            export-all="NON_EMPTY" 
            import-all="true" >
</classloading>
```

I just set the domain name in the xml to war name.It changes the JBoss class loader policy wherein it gives preference to jars from the application lib.That is what i exactly wanted :).